# WORDNET database access

Tags: nlp, wordnet

I have download wordnet(2.1) but i dont know how to access wordnet database?

Answer (score 5):

There are both libraries and file-formats [documented at the WordNet 3.0 Reference Manual](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/documentation/).  By the way, is there a reason you aren't using WordNet 3.0?

Answer (score 2):

You should check out NLTK. It's the easiest way to access WordNet. It's written in python.

Just to show you how simple it can be:

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
>>> wn.synsets('motorcar')
[Synset('car.n.01')]
```

You can find further documentation here:
http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/book/ch02.html
(scroll down for WordNet)

Oh and don't forget to actually download WordNet:

```
>>>import nltk
>>>nltk.download()
```

then just choose WordNet and download

Answer (score 2):

Highly recommend the MySql build at http://wnsqlbuilder.sourceforge.net/.  You can also search for a SQL Server version.  Big direct speed upticks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C++, Wordnet comes with an interface on its own. You should find them in your WN distribution.

If you are using C#, then sharpnlp.codeplex.com is the place for you, they have a Wordnet interface.

Wordnet also has a Perl distribution, but I don't know if they can be directly used because I dont use Perl.

Best regards,
David

Answer (score 0):

Install nlk and then use

```
 from nltk import wordnet
```

And then by using synsets you can compare words